# Windows 10 phone UWP lifecycle textBox

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have problem with saving and loading data from textBox.
I want after put some data to textBox (when user fill textBox) and save them in onSuspending method and load them in OnResuming or OnLaunched method.
I want to use LocalSettings.

The idea is that: user fill textBox and for example app crashed and when he will back all result are still in textBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an event handler for each of your textboxes `OnTextChanged()` and add this code inside: `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["TextboxName"] = TextblockName.Text;`

When the user is finished with the form and you don't need to save the content of textboxes anymore then on the submit button you can add this code to clear the data `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["TextboxName"] = null;` for each textbox.

Now to get the data after app is crashed and user opens it again, you can simply add the following code in your `Main()` method for each of your textboxes:

```
If(ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["TextboxName"] != null)
{
   TextboxName.Text = (string)ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["TextboxName"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks your example work, but I have one question: do you have any idea how use it in OnSuspending method? I have to prove saving data in OnSuspending.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm not sure how you can do this with `OnSuspending()`.

Comment: Maybe you have any other idea, how show lifecycle work I mean saving data in OnSuspending and loading data in OnLaunch or OnResume?

Comment: No sorry :/ I only know this solution.

Comment: @Icero: What's your obsession with saving state in an `OnSuspending` event handler? In case your application crashes with an unhandled exception, none of your code runs after that point (unless you install an unhandled exception filter). In particular, none of the lifecycle callbacks run. Maybe you should concentrate on writing better code, so that your app doesn't crash as much anymore?